# Porcentagem PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Não consigo realizar a porcentagem desta consulta .

Deveria pegar a soma do *"valor_convenio"* de cada município e dividir pela soma total geral do *"valor_convenio"* :

```
<h3>Entrada SQL SEM CALCULO DE PORCENTAGEM</h3>
SELECT
    nome_municipio,
        SUM(valor_convenio)<br/>
FROM
    paraiba.vigente<br/>
WHERE 
    convenente LIKE '%(MUNICIPAL)%'<br/>
GROUP BY
    nome_municipio<br/>
ORDER BY
    "Total Conveniado (R$)" DESC;<br/>


<h3>Exemplo de Saída ATUAL:</h3>------------------------------------------------------
<br/>|JOAO PESSOA.......|R$272.789.654,75|
<br/>|CAMPINA GRANDE|R$182.080.728,84|
<br/>|PIANCO...................|..R$35.392.580,61|
<br/>|SUME......................|..R$34.040.127,05|
<br/>|CABEDELO.............|..R$30.652.583,47|
<br/>|SOUSA....................|..R$22.075.733,70|
<br/>|PATOS.....................|..R$20.061.310,59|
<br/>-------------------------------------------------------

<h3>Exemplo de Saída QUE PRECISO:</h3>--------------------------------------------------------------
<br/>|JOAO PESSOA.......|R$272.789.654,75|..22%
<br/>|CAMPINA GRANDE|R$182.080.728,84|..15%
<br/>|PIANCO...................|..R$35.392.580,61|....3%
<br/>|SUME......................|..R$34.040.127,05|....3%
<br/>|CABEDELO.............|..R$30.652.583,47|....2%
<br/>|SOUSA....................|..R$22.075.733,70|....2%
<br/>|PATOS.....................|..R$20.061.310,59|....1%
<br/>--------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

No final de eu exporto para arquivo csv separados por ";" ficando nesse padrão:

```
JOAO PESSOA;272.789.655;22%<br/>
CAMPINA GRANDE;182.080.729;15%<br/>
PIANCO;35.392.581;3%<br/>
SUME;34.040.127;3%<br/>
CABEDELO;30.652.583;2%<br/>
SOUSA;22.075.734;2%<br/>
PATOS;20.061.311;2%<br/>
```

Comment: Porcentagem com relação a que? aqueles 22% ali no primeiro resultado é somente fictício?

Comment: Não sei se entendi corretamente sua dúvida, poderia reformular e dar mais detalhes? fiz uma simulação do problema, veja se te ajuda: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b64008/5

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515152/how-to-use-a-sql-window-function-to-calculate-a-percentage-of-an-aggregate  veja se ajuda "analytic functions" facilitam isto.

Comment: os 22% é a soma total do valor convenio dividido pelo valor convenio do municipio em questao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, você precisa de uma consulta que retorne a soma de todos os valores da coluna `valor_convenio`. A query então seria simples:

```
select
    sum (valor_convenio) as total
from paraiba.vigente
WHERE
    convenente LIKE '%(MUNICIPAL)%'
```

Além disso, você já possui a query que soma o `valor_convenio` agrupado por município (fiz umas modificações de alias pois a query não executava da forma que você a escreveu):

```
SELECT
    nome_municipio,
    SUM(valor_convenio) as total
FROM paraiba.vigente
WHERE
    convenente LIKE '%(MUNICIPAL)%'
GROUP BY nome_municipio
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

O que é necessário agora é apenas juntar as consultas para que você obtenha o valor da porcentagem. Para isso, pode ser utilizado um `join`. Ele serve basicamente para unir resultados de consultas complexas. Então adicionando a junção ficaria algo como:

```
SELECT
    nome_municipio,
    SUM(valor_convenio),
    SUM(valor_convenio) / total.total AS total
FROM paraiba.vigente, (
    select sum (valor_convenio) as total 
    from paraiba.vigente 
    WHERE convenente LIKE '%(MUNICIPAL)%'
) total 
WHERE convenente LIKE '%(MUNICIPAL)%' 
GROUP BY nome_municipio 
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

Se você executar a query acima, vai se deparar com o seguinte erro:

> ERROR:  column "total.total" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
>   LINE 1: ...nicipio, SUM(valor_convenio), SUM(valor_convenio)/total.tota...

O problema é que existe o uso de uma função de agrupamento `SUM` com 2 resultados de queries diferentes, e isso precisa ser adicionado numa cláusula `group by` para que as informações possam ser agregadas pela função. Como o valor da soma total da coluna `valor_convenio` é único para todos os municípios, você pode adicioná-lo na clásula `group by` sem impacto no resultado final. Assim, você teria algo como:

```
SELECT 
    nome_municipio, 
    SUM(valor_convenio),
    SUM(valor_convenio) / total.total AS total 
FROM paraiba.vigente, (
    select sum (valor_convenio) as total 
    from paraiba.vigente
    WHERE convenente LIKE '%(MUNICIPAL)%'
) total 
WHERE convenente LIKE '%(MUNICIPAL)%'
GROUP BY nome_municipio, total.total 
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

Para ajustar a query adicionando um formato de porcentagem, você pode fazer algo como o exemplo abaixo, usando a função de arredondamento `round` e o operador de concatenação de strings `||`:

```
SELECT 
    nome_municipio,
    SUM(valor_convenio),
    round((SUM(valor_convenio)/total.total)*100, 2) || '%' AS total
FROM paraiba.vigente, (
    select sum (valor_convenio) as total  
    from paraiba.vigente 
    WHERE convenente LIKE '%(MUNICIPAL)%'
) total
WHERE convenente LIKE '%(MUNICIPAL)%'
GROUP BY nome_municipio, total.total
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

Dica: Sempre que tiver queries complexas para construir, construa cada pedaço separadamente e depois pense na lógica de juntá-los. Assim fica bem mais fácil resolver problemas desse tipo.

Comment: deu certo, obrigado (: